# dash.exceptions.IncorrectTypeException: The output argument […] is not of type `dash.Output`

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I've been scratching my head over this bug for an hour now. I have the following callback function:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output("average_table", "data"),
     Output("average_table", "columns"),
     Output("worst_table", "data"),
     Output("worst_table", "columns"),
     Output("worst_0", "data"),
     Output("worst_0", "columns"),
     Output("worst_3", "data"),
     Output("worst_3", "columns"),
     Output("worst_5", "data"),
     Output("worst_5", "columns"),
     Output("worst_6", "data"),
     Output("worst_6", "columns")],
    [Input("upload-data", "contents"),
     State("upload-data", "filename")]
)
def updateTables(contents, filename):
    if contents is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    av, wo, st0, st3, st5, st6 = parseData(contents, filename)

    return av, columns, wo, columns, st0, columns_w, st3, columns_w, st5, columns_w, st6, columns_w
```

which trows the error seen in the title of the Topic. I've looked a similar posts could'nt find anything that resolves the issue.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Dokumente\DCDM Dashboard\app.py", line 140, in <module>
    @app.callback(
  File "E:\Dokumente\DCDM Dashboard\venv\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 879, in callback
    self._validate_callback(output, inputs, state)
  File "E:\Dokumente\DCDM Dashboard\venv\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 666, in _validate_callback
    raise exceptions.IncorrectTypeException(
dash.exceptions.IncorrectTypeException: The output argument `[<dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B237F0>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23AC0>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23B80>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23BE0>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23C40>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23CA0>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23D00>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23D60>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23DC0>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23E20>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23E80>, <dash.dependencies.Output object at 0x0000012C13B23EE0>]` is not of type `dash.Output`.
```

Comment: I don’t think you are allowed to mix input/state in the same list, they should be separate lists. Also, could you include import statements?

Comment: @emher I suppose you mean this?
`
dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        accept=".xlsx",
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ])
`

Comment: Please share a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can reproduce the problem.